# non-const non-type expression inside template

Tags: c++, templates

I tried finding this one but couldn't. I am new to C++ template programming. I have a situation like this -:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

enum DataType{
    FLOAT32,
    SIGNED32
     :,
     : (there can be other dataTypes as well)
};

struct SomeClass{
  DataType d;
  void* pointer;
};

void add(SomeClass a, SomeClass b)
{
    DataType dataType = a.d;
    using aDataType = std::conditional<dataType == FLOAT32 , float, int>;
}

int main()
{
    SomeClass a;
    a.d = FLOAT32;
    SomeClass b;
    b.d = SIGNED32;
    int* p = static_cast<int*>(malloc(sizeof(int)));
    *p = 4;
    b.pointer = p;

    float* p2 = static_cast<float*>(malloc(sizeof(float)));
    *p2 = 4.3;
    a.pointer = p2;

    add(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to find out the datatype of what's stored in a.pointer and b.pointer but this is giving a compile-error, saying the value of ‘dataType’ is not usable in a constant expression.

Comment: This is correct. Only constant expressions can be used as template parameters. The `dataType` in question will, of course, vary at runtime. Which part of this is unclear to you? Additionally, if you would like to learn C++, then learn C++, instead of C covered with a thick layer of make-up. This means `new` instead of `malloc`. This means no games with `void *`. One of the key features of C++ is type-safety. Use it.

Comment: Actually this kind of code is in my project where void* is used. I had to write a similar one to reproduce the issue. I wanted to know whether there could be solution for it.

Comment: Yes, there is a solution for it. This is exactly what std::variant is for. This "someclass" is just reinvention of C++17's variant template which can completely replace it with better performance and 100% type safety. No ugly void pointers. See your C++ book for more information, Stackoverflow is not really a replacement for a good C++ book.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use operator==, since the dataType is only known at runtime. What you are basically trying to do here is to mimic C-unions, which are quite unrelated to templates. Note, that once you receive SomeClass as a parameter, you can't really distinguish between the underlying types on compile time.

I would suggest this code:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

template<typename T, typename U>
void add(T* a, U* b)
{
    using aDataType = T; // Unnecessary, but for the example
}

int main()
{
    int i = 4;
    float f = 4.3;

    add(&i, &f);
    return 0;
}
```